# JProfiler trigger snapshot not saving JDBC events

Tags: java, jdbc, jprofiler

When using a timed trigger to save a snapshot the JDBC events data is not being saved (some other data is also missing but I'm most interesting in the JDBC events). The JDBC Hot spots and Telemetries has the correct data.

If I save the snapshot manually through the GUI all the data is saved correctly.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug with JProfiler?

JProfiler version 8.1.2

Edit:

Doing some more testing with the built in JDBC demo, it looks like it only saves the JDBC Event data that was created at the exact time of when the snapshot was taken. 
Sounds like a bug to me?

Comment: Do you do this with offline profiling or with the JProfiler GUI attached?

Comment: Both offline and with GUI attached

Comment: I cannot reproduce this for either offline profiling or profiling with the GUI. Can you send such a snapshot to support@ej-technologies.com?